# ReferenceError X (ViewChild ) is not defined when compile with AoT

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-compiler-cli

When I compile without **AoT** all is fine, but when compile with **AoT** I get this error

> ReferenceError: nameColumnHeader is not defined

I declared my `ViewChild` inside `.ts` file and inside `.html` file I set local variable like this `<div #nameColumnHeader></div>`
Is there an expected way to write `ViewChild` when compile with AoT ?

Comment: How did you write it? Why inside `.html`?

Comment: thanks for response, I said it works when compile without AoT... I write it inside my component template AFAIK it's an .html file :) and I use it inside ngOnInit... so what is the right behavior ? because without AoT it works and with it doesn't work !

Comment: Please post the code. Can't make sense of the comment.

Comment: here you are ts : http://pastebin.com/CUKU0cMx  and if you need tempalte : http://pastebin.com/fwrac4Lt  and if useful when I comment this ViewChild in particular so another get me error called 'end' it's reference to sidenav from material2 lib, I don't understand all is OK without AoT, thanks for help

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "viewchild in HTML". There is a `;` missing after `@ViewChild('end') end`

Comment: please apologize I edit my question I mean  I declared `#nameColumnHeader ` local variable  inside view, anyway it seems it works !!! But I don't understand, I was thinking semicolons in js/ts are optional, they aren't ? Why without AoT it compile ... donno

Comment: AoT has to do it's own parsing and processing of the code which can be implemented differently than in other tools. So adding the missing `;` fixed it?

Comment: yes thanks this resolve, still not understand why AoT parsing doesn't add semicolons automatically, maybe missfeature, and cli error is very poor and insigifiant why this doesn't tell me "semicolumn miss" or donno